# jOOQ Codegen with different MySQL DBs for dev, test and prod

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I'm using jOOQ with MySQL and having different DBs per stage (dev, test, prod).

The configuration in the pom.xml looks like this.

```xml
<generator>
    <database>
        <name>org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
        <includes>.*</includes>
        <excludes></excludes>
        <inputSchema>db_test</inputSchema>
    </database>
    <target>
        <packageName>ch.bls.nfdb.db</packageName>
        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
    </target>
</generator>
```

jOOQ uses the inputSchema and generates a class DbTest.

All SQL statements are prefixed with this schema name. And that's the problem. 
How do I configure the schema name for my prod database db_prod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map your schema either at code generation time or at runtime. Both options include not rendering a schema name in generated SQL at all:

#### At code generation time

```xml
<database>
    <name>org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
    <includes>.*</includes>
    <excludes></excludes>
    <inputSchema>db_test</inputSchema>

    <!-- Add this: -->
    <outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>

    <!-- Or this: -->
    <outputSchema>db_prod</outputSchema>
</database>
```

[More details here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-catalog-and-schema-mapping)

#### At runtime

```java
Settings settings;

// Add this
settings = new Settings().withRenderSchema(false);

// Or this
settings = new Settings().withRenderMapping(
    new RenderMapping().withSchemata(
        new MappedSchema().withInput("db_dev").withOutput("db_prod")));
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(connection, MYSQL, settings);
ctx.select().from(...).fetch();
```

[More details here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-render-mapping)

Comment: Thank you! The code generation works for me but I'm using Spring Boot so it would be great to have a way to set the input and output schema in application.properties. Is this already planed or should I create a feature request?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: I'm not aware of any such plans. You could create a feature request in Spring Boot. Curious though how they'd map arbitrary configuration lists to specific jOOQ configurations. If you do, please add a link to your request here, I'd love to follow the conversation.

Comment: Ok. I will do that. Currently there is only one configuration parameter for jOOQ in Spring Boot: spring.jooq.sql-dialect but as they create the DSLContext they should be able to do anything that is configurable in jOOQ

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Maybe, however, in order to make their implementations as forward compatible as possible, they would need to map generically between their notation and the jOOQ configuration, which seems to get hairy for many cases.

Comment: I created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16012

Comment: @LukasEder Is it possible to use `RenderMapping` if the input and output `db` is in two different database servers? If yes, how do I set it programmatically at runtime?

Comment: @RoshanUpreti: Might work. Can you please ask a new question with some details?

Comment: @LukasEder I've just created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865716/is-it-possible-to-use-render-mapping-if-the-input-and-output-db-is-in-two-differ

Comment: @RoshanUpreti: I see you've already been able to solve your problem

Comment: @LukasEder I did manage to figure out a solution. Took a while to wrap my head around it, but the solution was fairly simple and straightforward. I even figured out that `DSL.using(jooqConfig.derive(getDataSource()))` eliminates the need of `Connection` object.